# Is there any way to get hard disk temperature via the terminal in mac os

Tags: macos, hard-drive, temperature

I wanted to know how to monitor the temperature of your disk without using a 3rd party applications and using the terminal instead. Since there are applications that do this, there has be a way to view or retrieve this data via the terminal or some code.

All the place I looked said it wasn't possible to do it without using 3rd party applications or simply provided a 3rd party source of retrieving the information. So I wondered how those 3rd applications are doing it.

So i'm posting this here, If anyone has any information that's helpful i'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the temperature if the drive has a temperature sensor attached. iMacs definitely used to have these, causing havoc if you ever swapped out the drive.
Mac Pros don't. Laptops, I don't know, sorry.

As far as I'm aware, there's no simple command line method, without installing at least a 3rd party CLI tool, such as [iStats](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/iStats/1.6.1)

The standard consumer tool is [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/). There are others, but this seems the common one.

Comment: Alright thank you for the information.